# Left align most left icon, right align most right icon and space all even in between

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Envision a questionnaire scenario where you can answer with a slider (html range element).

I have a range selector (slider) in a div below the div I need to space the icons.
The most left icon should be "sad" and the most right icon should be "happy" (or vice versa - doesn't really matter), but - here is the catch I don't always have the same amount of icons (or texts) to display. Sometimes I have 3 icons, sometimes 5 - 6 or even 9 icons. But I really want to distribute the icons evenly.
But the most left icon (or text) should be starting at the most left Y of the slider and the  most right icon (or text) should be ending on the most right Y of the slider.

I have tried `::first` and `::last` css attributes, but they just push the first and last elements out of alignment. While the rest is distributed evenly it's just not evenly spaced.

Using bootstrap: I have tried putting the the icons in a col-12 div and the range element inside a col-10 with 2 col-1's on either side, but that really depends on your resolution for it to work.

So, the question: how can align the elements (icon or text) in such a way where the most left element is above the start of the slider and the last element is above the end of the slider while spacing the "in between elements" evenly?

Comment: We need a [mcve]

Comment: I know - this is what I always use as remark. But there is no reproducible example except "all is shit" - the point here: I have no base except bootstrap  (which is needed) the rest is just fuzzy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a full-width container for those icons and apply `display:flex; justify-content: space-between;` to it.

Comment: This is perfect indeed and exactly the answer I needed